# Como instanciar um Bean novamente após a sessão cair JSF 1.x

Tags: java, jsf

Boa tarde galera,

Estou quebrando a cabeça com algo que acredito que seja simples.

Seguinte, existe alguma maneira de instanciar um Bean e seus atributos "manualmente"? Eu tenho um bean configurado no xml com escopo de sessão e esse possui mais 4 propriedades que também precisam ser instanciadas. O Jsf faz isso quando acesso o Bean via action no menu, mas quando a sessão expira eu precisaria instanciar-lo novamente sem precisar acessar o menu.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: As propriedades são do usuário logado?

Comment: Isso, fica armazenado na sessão do usuário

Comment: Mas as propriedades, são dados do usuário ou são dados genéricos do sistema?